# Get only relevant portion of website

Tags: php, javascript, web, screen-scraping

How does [Evernote's Web Clipper plugin](http://www.evernote.com/about/download/web_clipper.php) or [Announcify plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mmiolkcfamcbpoandjpnefiegkcpeoan) only get relevant article/post/content part of the page? Here is an screenshot from evernote plugin:

[image]

No matter which website you visit which is completely different from other layout wises, these are always able to get you article/post/content part of the page.

Each website has different layouts, some have sidebar, some don't, different tags, for main/article/content part, some use `<article>` or `<section>` of HTML5 others use `<h1> > <p>`, some use `<h2> > <p>` and others don't use at all. So there are different combination of tags as well as layouts of websites.

Can anyone suggest a solution to getting **main** article/post/content please via Javascript or PHP?

Comment: Maybe it looks for the biggest `div` or other element on the page?

Comment: @Jivings: Biggest div will contain whole site, we want to be able to find the element which contains main/article part :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do a simple DOM parsing and search for the `<div>`s and `<p>`s containing more text (**text! not HTML code!**). However, regardless of the intelligent method you will choose for determining where the content is, you should start from **DOM parsing**, so let's have a look at DOM parsing PHP libraries.

Anyway, you can start from this:

> http://w-shadow.com/blog/2008/01/25/extracting-the-main-content-from-a-webpage/

Looks quite good, and gives technical explanations if you want to write something of your own.

Comment: This is a horrible solution. But probably the best.

Comment: Because DOM parsing makes me shudder. But your link seems interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Most blog engines give that div an id of 'content'.

- In javascript you would just do $('#content')
- In php you would do DOMDocument::getElementById('content').